Error While Fetching Insights for Instagram Media Type
I am trying to fetch Insights data using the Media API. However, when the response includes media with media_product_type: 'REELS', the error occurs.
Is this a bug? If not, could you please advise on how to handle this issue?
Request Sample:
 https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/{media-id}/insights?metric= impressions, replies, 
 shares, comments, plays, likes, saved, video_views, total_interactions, reach, 
 ig_reels_video_view_total_time, ig_reels_avg_watch_time, clips_replays_count, 
 ig_reels_aggregated_all_plays_count&access_token={access-token}

ERROR:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The Media Insights API does not support the impressions, replies metric for this media product type.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AyMK6Hdc8c0kgeG5PwtpWn4"
 }
}

It was working in previous days, but now it's starting to produce the issue described above. I don't see any updates in the documentation. Can someone tell me what the issue might be?
